# How can I override a type member of a class with the same base class?

Tags: scala, oop, generics, type-members

Sorry for the confusing title.

I am attempting to write some `Request` and `Response` classes for validation and parsing purposes. I'd like to have some guarantees of the type at compile-time, but still have runtime polymorphism. I have the following base classes:

```
abstract class Response()

abstract class Request() {
  type ResponseType = Response
  def ResponseClass: Class[_ <: ResponseType] = classOf[ResponseType]
}
```

so if I have an instance of type `_ <: Request`, I can parse, for instance a JSON response, with the correct type: `Json.parse(responseString).as[request.ResponseType]`.

I find that when I extend these classes, I am unable to `override` the `ResponseType`:

```
case class AddedFooResponse() extends Response

case class AddFooRequest() extends Request {
  override type ResponseType = AddedFooResponse
}
```

> error: overriding type `ResponseType` in class `Request`, which equals `this.Response`;
>    type `ResponseType` has incompatible type
>     `override type ResponseType = AddedFooResponse`

I am unsure why the types are incompatible. My current workaround is a bit clumsy, which is to bound the type in the base classes:

```
abstract class Response()

abstract class Request() {
  type ResponseType <: Response
  // cannot initialize because no concrete class
  def ResponseClass: Class[_ <: ResponseType] 
}
```

and simply override both the `ResponseType` and the `ResponseClass`:

```
case class AddedFooResponse() extends Response

case class AddFooRequest() extends Request {
  override type ResponseType = AddedFooResponse
  override def ResponseClass = classOf[ResponseType]
}
```

This requires a lot of (seemingly) unnecessary boilerplate for overriding the `ResponseClass`.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Why do you need to store the class of `ResponseType` in that way? I feel like there might be a better way to achieve what it is you need that doesn't require a `java.lang.Class`.

Comment: @MichaelZajac I have a validator that compares the `ResponseClass` to the class of the received `Response`. If I have the response type, it may become moot. If nothing else, this question is interesting. At best it's practical. See [here](http://ideone.com/z4cC8C) if you're interested.

Comment: I'd say that using `type ResponseType <: Response` is a step in the right direction, but using `classOf` with it doesn't work very well, which is why it needs to drop out of the abstract class. Otherwise you have an invariant type member.

Comment: @MichaelZajac So do you know how I might be able to achieve something like `request.ResponseType == typeOf[response]`? Perhaps that's the crux of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could get away by not setting a default value for this type:

```
abstract class RequestBase() {
  type ResponseType
  def ResponseClass: Class[_ <: ResponseType] = classOf[ResponseType]
}

type Request = RequestBase { type ResponseType = Response }

case class AddFooRequest() extends Request {
  override type ResponseType = AddedFooResponse
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that I can forego completely the `ResponseClass` by simply setting the `ResponseType` and matching based on the instance returned by whatever uses that `ResponseType`, lest it'll parse incorrectly and throw an exception.

```
abstract class Response
abstract class Request[+ResponseType <: Response]

case class FooResponse() extends Response {
  def greet = println("woo hoo!")
}

case class FooRequest() extends Request[FooResponse] {
  type ResponseType = FooResponse
}

val req: FooRequest = new FooRequest()
// Erase the type by making it an Object.
val resp: Object = new FooResponse()

resp.asInstanceOf[req.ResponseType] match {
  case fooResp: FooResponse => fooResp.greet
  case _ => println("This isn't good...")
}
```